# Stuck in "Let's Make A Bubble Map" D3 and TopoJson tutorial

Tags: d3.js

I'm following the ["Let's Make A Bubble Map"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/) tutorial by Mike Bostock, and am stuck at the step merging counties into states. The error I get is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" on the line

```
key='d.id.substring(0, 2)'
```

which makes sense, because there is nothing tagged to id. New to this.. Please help :(

Comment: I can't get [the final source to that tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9943478) to run either—though mine failed earlier with a different error, detailed [in this comment on the gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/9943478#gistcomment-1649388). Perhaps that step also is outdated?

Comment: I realized it depends on the version of d3 you're running. Make sure it's v0 and not v1, and it should run!